# Sql Server Creates Temp Tables Itself

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core-3.1

My sql server creates temp tables itself. I have no code includes create table. Also i don't know how it happen but somehow this user constantly run this sql command:

[image: sql commands]

[image: Temp tables]

Extra Informations:

I profiled this and i can tell this queries come from application. But how, i still don't know.

[image: Profiler Output]

There is a MERGE queries here, somehow app creates a lot of tables, and merge them with original ones but how and why doing that?

It's flow like:

1. Create a table (Named Like SmsQueueTemp83bd1bd5Output)
2. Merge it (MERGE [Gateway].[SmsQueue] WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS T USING (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Gateway].[SmsQueueTemp24a23c42] ORDER BY [ID]) AS S ON T.[ID] = S.[ID] WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT ([BulkId], [CallbackData],
   [CallbackUrl], [CheckSum], [CheckedReportDates], [ConsumerID], [DateCreated]... etc.)
3. Try to delete extra table (IF OBJECT_ID ('[Gateway].[SmsQueueTemp35cede3cOutput]', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE [Gateway].[SmsQueueTemp35cede3cOutput])

Edit 2: I solve the problem.See, i use "BulkInsertOrUpdate" method in "EFCore.BulkExtensions" package. I think this method creates new table, bulk insert all data and merge that into original table so it can manage insert and update same time. But since my method calling frequency was too high, it cannot delete temporarly created table. I stop using this method and problem solved.

Comment: For the record those are NOT temp tables. They are persistent tables with terrible names.

Comment: you can run a trace to see the application actually creating these. Or check default trace, there might be some clues there: 
select applicationName, e.name, x.*
from (
 select *
 from sys.traces s
 where s.is_default = 1
 ) s
cross apply ::fn_trace_gettable(path, 1) x
inner join sys.trace_events e
 ON e.trace_event_id = x.eventclass
 and e.name like '%Object:Created%'

Answer (score 1):

> My sql server creates temp tables itself.

No it does not.  Some user or application is creating these tables.

Comment: There is only one application uses this user and there is no raw sql in application, i use entity framework. How can it possible, i never wrote any alter commands

Comment: EF wouldn't do this by itself.  You'll need to troubleshoot.  Perhaps use Profiler or XEvent trace to capture the statements.